# Why does CoCreateInstance return error 0x8007007f "The specified procedure could not be found"?

Tags: windows, com, 32bit-64bit

In Windows 7 I have a COM object in a DLL, let's say it is `my_COM_object.dll`.

I have two versions of the dll, one is 32 bit and one is 64 bit, the first lives in `c:\bin32\` and the second lives in `c:\bin64\`.

I did `regsvr32 c:\bin32\my_COM_object.dll` and then I tried to create the 32 bit COM object with `CoCreateInstance` but the creation failed and the error was `0x8007007f` "The specified procedure could not be found".

What can be the cause of the error?

I was in a hurry and I solved the problem with a brute force technique: I deleted all the keys in the registry related to `my_COM_object.dll` and then I did again `regsvr32 c:\bin32\my_COM_object.dll` but I would like to know what `0x8007007f` means: it does not seem well documented.

Comment: 0x8007007F = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND).  This is typically returned from GetProcAddress() when the desired function cannot be found.  Not sure exactly how this relates to your problem, though.

Comment: If the DLL is improperly registered, COM will not be able to `GetProcAddress(DllGetClassObject)` the class factory.